# how to binding image width and height WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am trying to control my image height and width and it is not working. I want it to be for some cases 32X32 or 64X64, now here is my code and my xaml :

```
<Image Margin="0,1,5,1" Width="{Binding IconWidth}" Height="{Binding IconHeight}">
```

I'm also trying this in my xaml and it won't work :

```
<Image Margin="0,1,5,1" Width="{Binding Path="IconWidth"}" Height="{Binding Path="IconHeight"}">
```

my code in my view model is :

```
public int IconHeight
    {
        get { return height; }
        set
        {
            height = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("IconHeight");
        }
    }

    public int IconWidth
    {
        get { return width; }
        set
        {
            width = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IconWidth");
        }
    }
```

and every time I change the image size it won't work...
Can someone please help ?

thanks

Comment: Are you expecting the Image you see to stretch as you increase/decrease IconWidth/Height ?

Comment: Do you set the source object of the bindings somewhere? E.g. by setting the DataContext for the Image controls?

Comment: yes i want the image to be change as i change the size from 32 to 64, and yes i do set the source object from 64 to 32 and still not working...

Comment: "i do set the source object from 64 to 32" means you just change the value of the property IconWidth or IconHeight. That's not enough. For data binding you do not only have to specify the source property, but also the object that owns this property. There are several ways to do that. I'd suggest you start reading the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: but i am doing it like this :                                             public int IconHeight
        {
            get { return height; }
            set
            {
                height = value;
                
                RaisePropertyChanged("IconHeight");
            }
        }

        public int IconWidth
        {
            get { return width; }
            set
            {
                width = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IconWidth");
            }
        }